# How to set timeout for the dropdown menu in CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have created a Webform called result analysis. The form divides into course wise and subject wise.
When the user moves the mouse cursor onto subject wise the drop down list appears(B.E, M.C.A, M.B.A and M.Tech). When user moves cursor onto B.E the next dropdown list under B.E(AU, CS, EC, ME, CV,..) appears.
My problem is I am not able to select the option other then 1st option under B.E dropdown menu. The display just disappears as soon as I try to navigate my mouse cursor onto other options.
How can I set time(like 1sec so the dropdown menu will be visible for 1sec) which allows the user to select other options.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link rel = "StyleSheet" href = "StyleSheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="height: 398px">

            <br />
                                                                                                           
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Large" 
                Text="Result Analysis"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
       
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" 
                style="z-index: 1; left: 41px; top: 100px; position: absolute; height: 56px; width: 1050px">
                <ul id = "Result">

        <li class = "Size" style="margin-removed 33px; width: 162px;"> Course Wise
        <ul>
                <li class = "SizeSmall">B.E
                <ul>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton3" runat = "server" Width = "20%">AU</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton4" runat = "server" Width = "20%">CS</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton5" runat = "server" Width = "20%">CV</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton6" runat = "server" Width = "20%">EC</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton7" runat = "server" Width = "20%">IS</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton8" runat = "server" Width = "20%">IP</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton9" runat = "server" Width = "20%">ME</asp:LinkButton></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li class = "SizeSmall"><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton10" runat = "server"> MCA</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li class = "SizeSmall"><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton11" runat = "server"> MTech</asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li class = "SizeSmall"><asp:LinkButton ID = "LinkButton12" runat = "server"> MBA</asp:LinkButton>.</li>
         </ul>
         </li>
            <li class = "Size" style="width: 231px; margin-removed 33px"> Subject Wise</li>
        </ul>
                <br />
                <br />
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" 
                style="z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 174px; position: absolute; height: 19px; width: 1089px">
            </asp:Panel>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
div ul ul 
{
    display: none;
}
div ul li:hover &gt; ul 
{
    display: block;
}
div ul li ul:hover &gt; ul 
{
    display: block;
}
.TextAlign
{
    text-align : center;
}
.Position
{
     position : relative;
     float : left;
     list-style : none;
}   
#Result ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
#Result {
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 225px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 37px;
    width: 466px;
}
#Result &gt; li {
    float: left;
}
.Size
{
    font-size :x-large;
}
.SizeSmall
{
    font-size : large;
}
```

Below is the screenshot of result analysis webform :

[ScreenShot](https://plus.google.com/photos/105587850868503389652/albums/5147920337435402881/6143516897107850818?banner=pwa&authkey=COj33PCb2PHP3gE&pid=6143516897107850818&oid=105587850868503389652)

Comment: That is not a good thing to do I feel

Comment: Then what is the solution for that other then time delay? Please help

Comment: you can do it via JS..`onmouseover()` show the dropdown and `onmouseleave()` hide it

Comment: Abhishek, thank you for your comments. I figured it out. I just removed z-index from the style of panel and its working perfect. Here is the fiddle for that [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/wg2gspLb/1/). Thank you once again